# Keyboard Number Pad only works as directional inputs like arrow keys

Tags: keyboard

About a month ago I noticed that typing numbers on the right side numeric key pad of any keyboard I use now only serves as arrow keys.  For example, pressing **8=up**, **2=down**, **4=left**, **5=right**.  Holding Shift while typing the numbers results in normal function and a number will be the output.  **Numlock** has no effect on this.  The keyboard command to reverse this has no effect (**shift+numlock**).  The settings for **Mouse Keys** is disabled in Universal Settings.  The odd part is that while using the calculator, the number keys work fine.  Testing the key pad on the Windows side of my dual boot PC shows that this numeric key pad is working properly.  Testing other keyboards results in the same issue.  I've seen numerous posts about this issue and no one, I mean no one seems to have a solution for this.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04
**Output for Ubuntu version from Terminal**:

*Description:   Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal*

I'm not the only person dealing with this issue.  Can someone please help the Ubuntu community and give us a straight answer for how to fix this?  Thank you!

Comment: You have provided no Ubuntu version information. Please, [edit] your question and add this info. Also what happens if you enter the command `xev` and then press and release the ***NumLock*** key?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  After entering the xev command in terminal and pressing the numlock key, there is no event tracked.  This key works in Windows.  No keyboard that I try triggers an event after pressing NumLock

Comment: It's possible that the keyboard layouts are tied to the desktop (like Gnome, Unity, XFCE, Cinnamon, etc.) You might try using a different desktop to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Ok, so I should try Gnome or another flavor?  I can try that.  Thank you